# How to manage records by date ranges?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have the following structure in my DB in table `tariffs`:

```
  +------------+---------+
  |   Date     |  Value  |
  +------------+---------+
  | 01/01/2018 |    1    |
  | 02/01/2018 |    2    |
  | 03/01/2018 |    2    |
  | 04/01/2018 |    2    |
  | 05/01/2018 |    3    |
  | 06/01/2018 |    3    |
  | 07/01/2018 |    3    |
  | 08/01/2018 |    2    |
  +------------+---------+
```

In my view, I would like to have something like this:

```
  +-------------------------+---------+----------+
  |           Date          |  Value  |  Actions |
  +-------------------------+---------+----------+
  | 01/01/2018 - 01/01/2018 |    1    |   Delete |
  | 02/01/2018 - 04/01/2018 |    2    |   Delete |
  | 05/01/2018 - 07/01/2018 |    3    |   Delete |
  | 08/01/2018 - 08/01/2018 |    1    |   Delete |
  +-------------------------+---------+----------+
```

I want to manage a batch of tariffs by date range instead of managing each record separately.

How can I group the values by date ranges described above?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tariff.all.group_by(&:value).map{
    |k, v| {k=> v.map{|elem| elem.date}}
}.reduce({}, :merge).map{
    |k, v| {k => v.minmax}
}
```

1. Get all tariffs and group them by value ([group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by))
2. Extract dates into new array ([map](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Enumerable/map))
3. Convert array of hashes into single hash ([reduce](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce))
4. Finally get min and max date ([minmax](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/minmax))

---

Output:

```
[{1=>[Mon, 01 Jan 2018, Mon, 01 Jan 2018]},
{2=>[Tue, 02 Jan 2018, Thu, 04 Jan 2018]},
{3=>[Fri, 05 Jan 2018, Sun, 07 Jan 2018]}, ...]
```

---

Addition to comment:

If I got you right this will give you expected output:

```
tariffs = Tariff.all
grouped = [tariffs.first.value => [tariffs.first.date]]
prev = nil
tariffs.drop(1).each do |t|
    if prev.present? && t.value == prev.value
        grouped.last.values.first.push(t.date)
    else
        grouped.push(t.value => [t.date])
    end
    prev = t
end

grouped.map{|g| {g.keys.first => g.values.first.minmax}}
```

You could wrap it class method of `Traffic`

Comment: Thank you. But as you can see 08/01/2018 value is 2 the same as 02/01/2018 - 04/01/2018 and will be grouped with these values. And I will get `{2=>[Tue, 02 Jan 2018, Thu, 08 Jan 2018]}` all values between this dates will be ignored.

Comment: Could you clarify the criterion for grouping?

Comment: For example:
01/01/2018 => 1    
02/01/2018 => 2    
03/01/2018 => 2    
04/01/2018 => 2    
05/01/2018 => 3    
06/01/2018 => 3    
07/01/2018 => 3    
08/01/2018 => 2    

I would like to receive the following output:

`[{1=>[Mon, 01 Jan 2018, Mon, 01 Jan 2018]},
{2=>[Tue, 02 Jan 2018, Thu, 04 Jan 2018]},
{3=>[Fri, 05 Jan 2018, Sun, 07 Jan 2018]}, {2=>[Fri, 08 Jan 2018, Sun, 08 Jan 2018]}]`